# How to begin with creating a fork of a software?

Tags: firefox

I need to start work on creating a fork of the open-source web browser **Mozilla Firefox**, but I have no idea where to start. I'd be glad if someone could point me out in the right direction. I'd really, really appreciate the help.

Also, if my question does not belong here, please point out and suggest where I should post such questions. I was browsing through the StackExchange websites, and couldn't find a viable site. I could have overlooked/been careless, so if that's the case, please point me out in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like this is the right SE site. Have no idea what you should do, though.

Comment: The question is a bit vague though. You should start with making the actual fork, if you don't know how/where to do this, then that's what your first question should be, but then it might be borderline off-topic though.

Comment: Firefox is a very extensible software, are you sure what you want to do cannot be done with an extension or a plugin ?

Comment: There are two kinds of forks. Contributive forks, a temporary fork that allows you to work on a specific feature and later contribute it back to the upstream project, and there are disruptive forks, where you decide to create a entirely new project based on an existing one. Which one are you planning ?

Comment: @YolandaRuiz to be honest, I've never thought about that. It's for a project of mine, so I think I'd go with the second choice. I'd be glad if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might also want to just use the rendering engine (Gecko), and not create a fork at all. If you do want to create a fork, find where the code is hosted, download it, then put it up on github under a new account. If the code is already on github, there's a button you can press to fork a repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should ask yourself very hard whether a fork is the best solution because it will pose many kinds of issues. Ask yourself at least the following:

1. Can your project be completed as an *extension* of the original software?
2. Can your project be contributed to the upstream project instead of creating a new software?
3. ¿Does the upstream project license allows the type of fork intended? Not all types of forks are allowed depending on the license.

If after a good while you decide that a fork is the only solution, the general approach:

1. Find where the source code of the project lives and which version control system it uses.
2. Clone the repository to a local copy on your machine.
3. Follow the instructions (if any) to rebuild the software.
4. Make sure at this point that you can tweak the software and run your modified version.
5. Ask yourself again if you really want to do a full fork.
6. Review the instructions (if any) on how to package the software.
7. Find a place to host your modified version of the source code.
8. Find a way to synchronize your version with the modifications done by the upstream project. This is especially important to keep compatibility and merging bug fixes.

Firefox is a huge codebase. I don't want to discourage you but if you are not already experienced you should probably not start your own Firefox fork. My advice would be to at least [create an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) first, to become more familiar with Firefox programming model on a smaller scale. Extensions can be very powerful and do a lot of things.

For the first point, the instructions on how to get the source code of Firefox can be found here: [Getting Mozilla Source Code Using Mercurial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I'm going to try creating an extension first.